# Limiting the columns that can be written

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I created the rule by using [the Firebase Bolt compiler](https://firebase.com/docs/security/bolt/quickstart.html).

```
    {
     "rules": {
       "users": {
          "$user_id": {
           ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['settings', 'provider', 'email', 'privilege_type', 'address_city', 'address_state', 'dt_created', 'dt_updated'])",
           "settings": {
             ".validate": "newData.val().length > 0 && newData.val().length < 1000"
....
           ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user_id",
           ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user_id"
         }
       }
     }
  }
```

And I tested with PHP script

```
<?php
require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');

const DEFAULT_URL = 'https://MYAPP.firebaseio.com/';
const DEFAULT_TOKEN = 'MYTOKEN';
const DEFAULT_PATH = '/users';

$firebase = new \Firebase\FirebaseLib(DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_TOKEN);

// --- storing an array ---
$test = array(
        "foo" => "bar",
        "i_love" => "lamp",
        "id" => 42
);
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$firebase->set(DEFAULT_PATH . '/' . $dateTime->format('c'), $test);

// --- storing a string ---
$firebase->set(DEFAULT_PATH . '/name/contact001', "John Doe");

// --- reading the stored string ---
$name = $firebase->get(DEFAULT_PATH . '/name/contact001');

var_dump($name);
```

So, the data was entered

```
{
  "2015-11-12T12:46:51 01:00" : {
    "foo" : "bar",
    "i_love" : "lamp",
    "id" : 42
  },
  "2015-11-12T12:48:27 01:00" : {
    "foo" : "bar",
    "i_love" : "lamp",
    "id" : 42
  },
  "name" : {
    "contact001" : "John Doe"
  }
}
```

My question (sorry if this is a dumb question).

I am trying to limit the columns that can be written by the application, in accordance with the rules confined (

```
".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['settings', 'provider', 'email', 'privilege_type', 'address_city', 'address_state', 'dt_created', 'dt_updated'])"
```

But the PHP script can write and create different columns.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/FZ4JMYB_mFo

Comment: Thank you for reviewing the text. @david

Comment: Sorry for duplicate question , my co-worker posted the same question on google groups.  Just saw now, he did not tell me. @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**+1 For using Bolt!**

You need to have different permissions for your PHP server than your application.

If you **trust** your PHP Server, you can store a secret key for your Firebase on it. Then you can authenticate with that custom token and it will give you total access to the Firebase database.

However, if you don't want that much power you can generate a custom token that only has certain permissions you specify.

Check out the documentation on custom login. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html